# Complexity of Gaussian Elimination over a Finite Field

Tags: algorithm-design, post-quantum-cryptography, finite-field, complexity, computational-complexity-theory

I read somewhere that the complexity of solving a Linear $n\times n$ system over a Finite Field $\Bbb F_q$ using Gaussian Elimination is $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ operations in $\Bbb F_q$.

What's the role of $\Bbb F_q$ here in the complexity?

Also, what's the cost of this algorithm in terms of $q$ and $n$?

Answer (score 3):

The classic Gaussian Elimination algorithm is $O(n^3)$ runtime regardless of specific field and the Matrix, so in this case a finite field $F_q$ of order $q$ doesn't play a role in the complexity. This runtime is due to the fact that you are zeroing out entries in columns column-by-column to get into row reduced echelon form.

For matrices in $GL(n, q)$, the set of $n\times n$ invertible matrices in the finite field of $q$ elements, Andrén et al. in 2007, demostrated a striped Gaussian elimination in

- [On the complexity of matrix reduction over finite fields](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196885807000711)

which can shave off a $\log_q n$ factor by attempting to pick row operations that simultaneously zero out entries in multiple columns by using the finite field structure.

They proved that up to a constant factor this algorithm is best possible as almost all matrices in $GL(n, q)$ need asymptotically at least $\frac{n^2}{2 \log_q n}$ operations.

Demetres, in 2014 showed that the *striped elimination algorithm* is asymptotically optimal by proving that almost all matrices in $GL(n, q)$ need asymptotically at least $\frac{n^2}{\log_q n}$ operations.

- [The Asymptotic Complexity Of Matrix reduction Over Finite Fields](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.5826.pdf)

Comment: It's always O(n^3) field operations, but the complexity of those operations has to vary with q, doesn't it?

Comment: Is it true that the cost is O(q^2 n^3) or O(q^2 n^2/log_q (n)) ?

Comment: @bmm6o the complexity of those field operations does vary with $q$. See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2068/complexity-of-arithmetic-in-a-finite-field

Comment: @Kunal can you clarify where the $q^2$ term is coming from?

Comment: @TomRidley Let k be the binary length of q. Since above algorithm requires $O(n^3)$ operations in $F_q$, and as one q-modular multiplication time cost is $O(k^2)$, therefore the total time cost is  $O(k^2 \cdot n^3)$. I could be wrong on that, please correct me if its not making sense somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: @Kunal Right! Then you'd be measuring operations in terms of bit operations. The cost is $O(n^3)$ field operations where we consider multiplication and addition operations as a single (one) operation.  So if you wanted bit operations the basic analysis would be what you stated in the previous comment. You can actual asymptotically do better on multiplication than $O(k^2)$ bit operations per multiplication where $k$ is the bit-length. This improvement is via Karatsuba's algorithm or FFT algorithm, there are many fast multiplication algorithm variants you can look up.

Comment: @TomRidley Thanks! If we are doing general analysis then what is cost that should I work with? The classical one or the fastest one?

Comment: @Kunal Others have their own opinion, but the classical one is the clearest in terms of readability and you can always state somewhere in your analysis that this multiplication cost can be lowered.

Comment: @TomRidley Thanks!